# Test a PhoneGap application on a real device

Tags: ios, testing, cordova, device

I built an application using Phonegap and I tested it on the iPhone Simulator.
Now I want to "send" it to the iPad, can somebody explain me how to handle that ?

Of course I've got an apple id and all others stuff...
I made the "provisioning profile" for the iPad, but I don't understood how I can run it on the device. If somebody can explain me or redirect me to a good tutorial for this kind of "testing development". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Apple ID and the ipad is properly provisioned, then you simply need to change where you are building to in xcode. Click on the button next to the "run" and "stop" buttons in xcode. The button will be the name of your project followed by "nameOfProject>iPad 4.3 Simulator" or something similar. Change this to be "iOS device name of ipad", the ipad you have plugged into the computer. Now rebuild and run.

Answer (score 2):

A way to distribute application without asking user to copy provisioning profile and application file to iTunes and then sync iPhone with it. Now, only thing that they need to do is to click on the link in e-mail, which will open website on device and there they can click to install application and profile on the iPhone.

http://blog.amarkulo.com/ad-hoc-profiles-and-application-distribution-via-web

Other reference :

http://support.twixlmedia.com/kb/epublisher-builder-application/how-do-i-create-the-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-my-ad-hoc-build

Answer (score 2):

use "run" instead of "emulate".

I've only used cordova but `cordova run <osname>` will install it on your  device if it's plugged in.
ie:

`cordova run ios` (I refuse to pay 99$ so not tested but it should)

`cordova run android` (works beautifully)

Comment: So does this work by simply plugging in the iPhone and doing Cordova run? Do you have to cd anywhere?

Comment: @James111 you would need to be in your Phonegap / Cordova project directory first

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(. I don't have xCode installed, is that a problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is a bit of a shortcut/cheat. But what i've done was do phonegap serve and then open the IP address that it provides you on my Iphone...It's pretty much the same as having it run on your device as an APK!

```
Step One:
```

cd to your directory and run `phonegap serve`

```
Step two:
```

On your Iphone/Android/Device open your web-browser (e.g safari) and type in the IP phonegap has given you.

```
Step three:
```

Have fun seeing your app work :)

However if you're using some of phonegaps features (gps, etc...) then these won't work. This solution is a quick and easy way of viewing your app that doesn't use any hardware controls (e.g a jquery mobile app)